# Issues with the current location image

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios8.2

I'm using the Google Maps SDK to display a map in my iOS app. Actually, in prior iOS versions (<=8.1) the default blue icon for current location displays correctly, but now in the iOS 8.2 simulator the blue dot looks like this

.[image]

I'm following the exact steps from the [google maps SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)

To show the current location I just do:

```
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you also use  (CLLocation*) myLocation [read, assign]?
If My Location is enabled, reveals where the user location dot is being drawn. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a04faba924be73a0ea5bb9ae300da1c9a

Comment: @Verma I think problem has nothing to do with that. I don't know if I was clear, but the dot is being drawn, the location is correct, and the blue dot is there, but it has a strange square white image as background in iOS 8.2. In prior iOS versions the dot looks perfect.

Comment: Also seeing this. @FabKremer - have you found a solution yet?

Comment: you got any solution ??? @FabKremer

Comment: @amitgupta nope, even after upgrading to their latest version no fix to that dot. Very odd. On the other hand the dot is ok in my phone so I forget this bug :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug. This will not show in real devices. This might be due to drawing the current location on the map in simulator.